# Promedio en excel de celdas separadas e ignorando #DIV/0

Tags: excel

Tengo tres valores en excel en tres celdas/columnas distintas y separadas a los que quiero sacarles el promedio, pero uno de esos valores es #¡DIV/0. ¿Cómo hago para ignorar el #¡DIV/0 e igual me arroje el promedio teniendo en cuenta que están separadas? ya que si estuvieran juntos con la función promedio lo ignoraría, pero así separados hay datos distintos de por medio que no me interesan, y si lo hago manual así separado no ignora el #¡DIV/0 y no arroja promedio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola podrías intentar hacerlo con la función si.error(formula),"valor que deas mostrar si sale un valor nulo o algo así"

Comment: Lo que necesito es que arroje el promedio de tres valores, y que si hay un valor #¡DIV/0 lo ignore en ese caso y saque promedio de los otros valores, si hay dos #¡DIV/0 entonces muestre el otro valor. Son muchos registros y El valor #¡DIV/0 a veces está en el primer valor, a veces en el segundo y a veces en el tercero, a veces en dos de ellos y a veces no está, por eso quiero un promedio que lo ignore

Answer (score 1):

Puedes beneficiarte de funciones que trabajen con matrices, como SUMA.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula es:

`=SUMA(--(ESNUMERO(A4:E4))*SI.ERROR(A4:E4;0))/SUMA(--(ESNUMERO(A4:E4)))`

Lo que hace es que mira primero cuántos valores son números y los divide por el total de números. Sin embargo, si tu promedio siempre va a ser dividir entre 3, independientemente del número de errores, prueba entonces así:

`=SUMA(--(ESNUMERO(A4:E4))*SI.ERROR(A4:E4;0))/3`

Answer (score 0):

espero te sirva, la función reemplaza por "" el error y el promedio se calcula sin inconvenientes. (+ info https://bit.ly/3D9oMHX)

=SI(C9;C8/C9;"")

te dejo la imagen con las fórmulas y un ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]